# Immutable data and locking

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic, locking

Is there any reason to provide a locking mechanism for (what would otherwise be) immutable data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, no.  One of the major advantages of using immutable data is that you can avoid locking, as you have an implicit guarantee that the data is "current" and nobody, including you, can modify it.

Comment: Typically? That sounds like a loophole. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @trinithis I put that in specifically because you didn't specify a language, platform, or framework, etc.  I don't know of any language that would have problems with immutable data in a threading situation, but I don't want to completely close the door, as I, personally, haven't used every one out there.  However, with the major languages, it should be safe...

Answer (score 3):

It may desirable in some cases to have a read-only interface provide an AcquireReadLock method, if some implementations of that interface may require locking.  An immutable object which implements the interface would not necessarily have to do anything in response to an AcquireReadLock request, but it would have to provide at least a stub implementation for that method; users of the method would be expected to call AcquireReadLock before attempting to perform a sequence of reads which might yield undesirable results if some other thread mutates the object between them (note that even if the object can't be mutated using the read-only interface, the existence of a read-only interface doesn't imply that the object won't be mutated via other means).  Further, even if an otherwise-immutable object wouldn't need locking, it might still want to have an option to "simulate" locking so as to confirm that consumers of the object acquire and release the lock properly.

Answer (score 1):

No, not if it is indeed completely immutable.